# Using a payment gateway to programatically pass money after some time

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

So my question is kinda hard to explain (I'm not sure how to do that...), but here's an example.

Someone will pay a value for a service in my platform... I'll keep this money until the person gets the service done, and after that I'll autorize that money to be passed to the person that made the service. But I'll keep like 10% of that money for me, and pass 90% of the money to the person that made the service.

I'm interested in the technical way of doing that, that may be using a payment service (like stripe, paypal or something else), or maybe doing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PayPal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) to construct simple or complex payment scenarios.

In a standard merchant account with credit card processing, you could do a Authorize Only transaction on a credit card, and later Capture the full amount.

> Authorization You request an authorization when a customer makes a
>   purchase. An authorization, provided by the customer’s card issuing
>   bank, confirms the cardholder’s ability to pay, ensuring that the
>   customer's credit card account is in good standing with sufficient
>   funds to complete the purchase.
>
> Capture After providing a service/product to the customer, you
>   ‘capture’ the relevant information from the authorization and submit
>   it in a capture/settlement request that your processor uses to
>   initiate a funds transfer between the customer's credit card account
>   and your checking account.

This is what merchants that ship real goods do; they authorize the full amount, and then capture the actual funds when the items ship. You could then retain the 10% and pay out the rest separately.

See [What is the difference between Authorization, Capture, and Sale?](https://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=C35&actp=RSS)